# Ofstream does create but doesn't write to file

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

Here is the code:

```
void makefiles(char* filename) {
    ifstream file(filename, ios::in);

    // number of entries in main file 
    int size = 0;

    // names is the vector that holds entries 
    vector<string> names;
    string tmpstr;

    while (getline(file, tmpstr)) {
        string toadd = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < tmpstr.size(); i++) {
            if (tmpstr[i] != '|')
                toadd += tmpstr[i];
            else
                break;
        }
        if(count(names.begin(), names.end(), toadd) == 0)
            names.push_back(toadd);
        size++;
    }
    file.close();

    ofstream userfile;
    file.open(filename, ios::in);
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        userfile.open(string(getenv("TEMP")) + "\\" + names[i] + ".txt", ios::out);
        
        cout << string(getenv("TEMP")) + "\\" + names[i] + ".txt" << endl;
        
        while (getline(file, tmpstr)) {
            if (tmpstr.rfind(names[i], 0) == 0) {
                userfile << tmpstr << endl;
                userfile.flush();
            }
        }
        userfile.close();
    }

    file.close();


}
```

This function is being called from main, filename contains some formatted text, like email database of the next view:

```
gottaletitout@gmail.com|timetogo@gmail.com|06.01.2023|21:09:30|born in the abyss|156
gottaletitout@gmail.com|timetogo@gmail.com|06.01.2023|21:09:30|born in the abyss|156
a@gmail.com|b@gmail.com|23.12.2009|13:52:16|prikol|13
hottaletitout@gmail.com|timetogo@gmail.com|06.01.2023|21:09:30|aorn in the abyss|156
```

Thus, one line is one entry

In conclusion, I get many empty files that have the names i want, but, again, they are empty

I tried adding right after opening userfile:

```
if(!userfile){
    cout << "File is not opened" << endl;
    return;
}
```

But it doesn't help because !userfile = false

I tried instead of userfile << tmpstr << endl, using userfile << tmpstr << flush;

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The writing of the output file (after opening) is in a loop, and subject to a number of conditions.   Try checking if the loop iterates at all (if it doesn't, no output will be produced) and if the various `tmpstr.rfind()` calls are producing a zero value.   Also, what do you expect to happen on iterations of the loop after the first - the first iteration will read to the end of `file`, and subsequent iterations will read starting at the end of the file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code is incomprehensible - at the very least check that the files opened

Comment: @madhur4127 i'm calling this function like:
```
int main(int argc, char* argv){
    makefiles(argv[1]);
}
```
The filename (the "database") is passed to program as comand line argument

Comment: sounds like the first call to `getline(file, tmpstr)` is failing so nothing is ever written to the file

Comment: You are only writing one file. On the first iteration of the last `for` loop, with `i==0`, the inner `while` loop reads `file` all the way to EOF. On all subsequent iterations, `file` is already at EOF and all `getline` calls fail immediately. So all the files but the first (named after `names[0]`) are created but never written to.

Comment: There should be no need for closing or flusing files. streams are RAII objects and should take care of that for you. Also you could leave all the error handling to  exception handling `ofstream.exceptions ( ifstream::badbit );` and get some extra information from the exception `what()`.

Comment: @JosephWilliamsen you're doing too many things in that function. You're first skimming to get the names and then reading again with simultaneous writes. Too much scope to debug. You should [use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) and find the actual problematic code. Of course this comment doesn't help you immediately but shows you path to resolve such issues yourself and ask concise question benefitting everyone.

Comment: Note that in `ifstream file(filename, ios::in);` the `, ios::in` is redundant. That's what the initial `i` stands for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing at most one file. On the first iteration of the last `for` loop, with `i==0`, the inner `while` loop reads `file` all the way to EOF. On all subsequent iterations, `file` is already at EOF and all `getline` calls fail immediately. So all the files but the first (the one named after `names[0]`) are created but never written to.

Comment: Yeah, after you mentioned it, i added ```file.clear(); file.seekg(0, ios::beg);``` at the end of iteration, and everything is working now
thanks